# Get the First Src from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

In Below JSON, there are two src , namely **image1 , image2**, Right now i am fetching both the src & its x values using `foreach` and displaying in javascript code, but i need to fetch only **first** src : `image1` & its x value 100....

**JSON**

```
  {  
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,     
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,          
          "y" : 0,         
          "name" : "L2a"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,            
              "src" : "image1",
              "y" : 0,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            },
            {

              "x" : 0,
              "y" : 0,             
              "name" : "L2b-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,             
              "src" : "image2",
              "y" : 0,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            },
            {            
              "x" : 0,
              "y" : 0,            
              "name" : "L2C-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" :22,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0, 
      "width" : 612,      
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
let jsonData = {
  

  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 10,   
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 20,          
          "y" : 30,         
          "name" : "L2a"
        },
        {
          "x" : 40,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 50,            
              "src" : "image1",
              "y" : 60,              
              "name" : "L2b-1"
            },
            {
              
              "x" : 70,
              "y" : 80,             
              "name" : "L2b-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 90,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 100,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 105,             
              "src" : "image2",
              "y" : 110,             
              "name" : "L2C-1"
            },
            {            
              "x" : 120,
              "y" : 130,            
              "name" : "L2C-2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 140,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 150,      
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};

function getAllSrc(layers){
  let arr = [];
  layers.forEach(layer => {
    if(layer.src){
      arr.push({src: layer.src, x: layer.x});
    }
    else if(layer.layers){
      let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
      if(newArr.length > 0){
        newArr.forEach(({src, x}) =>{
          arr.push({src, x: (layer.x + x)});
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

function getData(data) {
  let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
  for (let {src, x} of arr){
  document.write("src :" + src);
 document.write("<br>");
 
 document.write("x:" + x);
 document.write("<br>");
  }   
  
}
getData(jsonData);
```

https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/WmZPwX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return arr[0];` or `return arr.length?arr[0]:null;` would provide an obvious quickfix for that.

On the other hand, you can not `break` a `forEach` loop, the "best" you could do is to throw an exception from it, which is pretty nasty. So if the concern is about looping over a long data structure in vain, you could rather fall back to an old-school `for` loop and then you can `break` or `return` from it directly:

```js
let jsonData = {"layers":[{"x":10,"layers":[{"x":20,"y":30,"name":"L2a"},{"x":40,"layers":[{"x":50,"src":"image1","y":60,"name":"L2b-1"},{"x":70,"y":80,"name":"L2b-2"}],"y":90,"name":"user_image_1"},{"x":100,"layers":[{"x":105,"src":"image2","y":110,"name":"L2C-1"},{"x":120,"y":130,"name":"L2C-2"}],"y":140,"name":"L2"}],"y":150,"name":"L1"}]};

function getFirstSrc(layers){
  for(let i=0;i<layers.length;i++){
    let layer=layers[i];
    if(layer.src)
      return {src: layer.src, x: layer.x};
    if(layer.layers){
      let first=getFirstSrc(layer.layers);
      if(first)
        return {src: first.src, x: layer.x+first.x};
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(getFirstSrc(jsonData.layers));
```

Comment: @vickeycolors you are right, I did not understand the summing requirement - edited the return value accordingly.

Comment: Instead of displaying output in console, can you please help to display in page ? i tried this : `document.write(src: first.src, x: layer.x+first.x);` , but not worked for me....

Comment: also i integrated your code in my file : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/WmZBmg , but its not fetching src & its x value , please check & help me.....

Comment: @vickeycolors in the codepen link, the `var mask = ...` part got inside the `getFirstSrc` function. I think you want those lines somewhere else, since they certainly will not get executed in `getFirstSrc` as it simply returns after finding `src`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always grab the first item of an array (in this case an object), and display the information like this:

```
function getData(data) {
  let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers)[0];

  document.write("src :" + arr.src);
  document.write("<br>");

  document.write("x:" + arr.x);
  document.write("<br>");
 }
```

Then you don't need the for-loop since you'd have only one object to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks, i updated your code : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/RdLdax but its not displaying anything.....

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first element of arr you can use:

```
arr[0].src
```

and

```
arr[0].x
```

To get just the values for the first element.